# Android: Custom View returns to initial layout after soft keyboard appers

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-softkeyboard

I have a strange problem with my Custom View Group:

It is an extended FrameLayout representing a custom toggle button which has a handler moved on the left and on the right. (ala iPhone switch toggle button)
I move this handler by this line of code:

```
  mHandler.layout(0, 0, right, 0);
```

But when another view in my activity, an EditText, gains the focus, then the soft keyboard appears. Well, this event brings my Custom View Group in the initial configuration (if i had switched the custom view group in a "state ON" configuration, it turns on the initial "state OFF" configuration.

It's like the system doesn't remember that layout has changed after the Activity.onCreate().

Does anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that. It wasn't a issue about onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState because the activity doesn't go onPause or whatever.
I noticed that after my custom view loses the focus, it calls its onLayout method with the flag changed = false.

The simplest thing i've tought is to override that method with this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    if( changed ){
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }

}
```

That fixed the issue. My layout view changes only when i want and not when it loses the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You should override [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29) in your custom view and do whatever is necessary to save the internal state.

If you are deriving from an existing View class then don't forget to call the parent class implementations for saving the instance state.